# GoogleMaps SDK crashing app after modularization of project

Tags: swift, xcode, sdk, crash, maps

I have a working project with GoogleMaps in it that works fine. I made a copy of that project to make the project modular and now I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to open the map.

here is my pod configuration:

```
def shared_pods
    ...
    pod 'GoogleMaps', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'GooglePlaces', :modular_headers => true
end

def application_pods
    ...
end


def core_application_pods
...
end


target 'Application' do

  project 'Application/Application.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for Application

  shared_pods
  application_pods

  target 'ApplicationTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ApplicationUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'Core' do

    project 'Core/Core.xcodeproj'

    # Pods for Core

    shared_pods
    core_application_pods

    target 'CoreTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end
end

# Static libraries
static_libraries = ['GoogleMaps', 'GoogleMapsBase', 'GoogleMapsCore']#, 'GooglePlaces']

post_install do |installer|
puts "Running post_install script"

puts "Fix static_libraries"
installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
    unless ['Pods-Application'].include? aggregate_target.name
        aggregate_target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
            config_file.frameworks.subtract(static_libraries)
            xcconfig_path = aggregate_target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
            config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
        end
    end
end
...
end
```

I even tried putting both pods in shared_pods, enable/disable modular_headers and there is no difference in the outcome.

Here is some of the code which creates the UIGMapsView object. The object is created successfully and Maps delegates are fired before the crash..

```
final fileprivate func setupMapViewConstraints() {
        if self.mapView == nil {
            let mapView = UIGMapsView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
            mapView.gmapDelegate = self
            mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
            self.mapView = mapView
        }

        if let mapView = self.mapView {

            self.view.addSubview(mapView)
                self.view.sendSubviewToBack(mapView)

            let views : [String: UIView] = ["mapView": mapView]
            let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mapView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
            let horizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[mapView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(vertical + horizontal)

            autoreleasepool {
                mapView.startMonitoringLocation()
                mapView.backToMyPosition()
            }
        }
    }
```

The screen opens up and about 1 second in that screen the crash appears. (I can even see the blue dot in the middle of the map but the map is all grey...)

I even tried enabling Zombie to try to catch whats is causing this but not much of help there too... here is the screenshot:

[image: crash screenshot]

Does anyone know what might be causing this crash?

Thanks in advance!

EDITED:

I tried the solution mentioned below and Link errors came up on build time.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
>         type metadata for Natura.UIGMapsView in UIGMapsView.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC6Natura11UIGMapsView in UIGMapsView.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMutablePath", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIGMapsView.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIGMapsView.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraUpdate", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIGMapsView.o
>         objc-class-ref in SearchConsultantOnMapViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UIGMapsView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I had an extra line to the post script which was:

```
unless ['Pods-Application'].include? aggregate_target.name
```

So the solution proposed was not set the the main project, only for the Core. But when I take that line off the error above about the undefined symbols appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I finally did a workaround to fix this issue. It's not ideal but it's the best option given the circunstancies.

So if you have a similar issue I hope this helps.

GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces do not work well if imported on 2 projects (some bug duplicates the pod and you end up with 2 frameworks on the project at runtime and get the crash because it doesn't know which one to use)

My workaround was to set GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces only in my Core project. here is the Podfile:

```
def shared_pods
    ...
end

def application_pods
    ...
end


def core_application_pods
    ...
    pod 'GoogleMaps', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'GooglePlaces', :modular_headers => true
end


target 'Application' do

  project 'Application/Application.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for Application

  shared_pods
  application_pods

  target 'ApplicationTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ApplicationUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'Core' do

    project 'Core/Core.xcodeproj'

    # Pods for Core

    shared_pods
    core_application_pods

    target 'CoreTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end
end
```

Make sure you do not have GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces in Application project under Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries

I linked GooglePlaces in my Core project under Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries (you have to manually choose the framework, it's inside the Pods folder). Not sure if this is necessary because I didn't link GoogleMaps and it's working also.

Create a custom class that will work as a shell for your Application project to use GoogleMaps framework like:

```
import GoogleMaps

public class NTGMSServices : GMSServices {
    convenience override init() {
        self.init()
    }
}

public class NTGMSCameraUpdate : GMSCameraUpdate {}
```

and

```
import GooglePlaces

public class NTGMSPlace : GMSPlace {}
public class NTGMSAutocompletePrediction : GMSAutocompletePrediction {}
public class NTGMSAutocompleteFetcher : GMSAutocompleteFetcher {
    convenience init() {
        self.init()
    }
}
public class NTGMSPlacesClient : GMSPlacesClient {}
public class NTGMSAutocompleteFilter : GMSAutocompleteFilter {}
public protocol NTGMSAutocompleteFetcherHandlerDelegate  {
    func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [NTGMSAutocompletePrediction])
    func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error)
}

public class NTAutocompleteFetcherHandler : NSObject {
    public var delegate: NTGMSAutocompleteFetcherHandlerDelegate?
}
extension NTAutocompleteFetcherHandler : GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {

    public func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
        delegate?.didAutocomplete(with: predictions as! [NTGMSAutocompletePrediction])
    }

    public func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {
        delegate?.didFailAutocompleteWithError(error)
    }
}
```

Make sure you change all the vars you used in Application project to these new types and import Core instead of importing GoogleMaps or GooglePlaces and that you adapt the protocol if you are using GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate

Make sure you clean and rebuild the entire project.

This way the GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces frameworks will not get duplicated due to the CocoaPods bug or the Google's implementation of the framework.

You can follow if Cocoapods fixes this issue [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9586)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is caused by inconsistency of having multiple binaries loaded inside the application. This usually happens when trying to use a static pod (like **GoogleMaps**) in multiple modules (or a multi-module architecture).

Typically what I did in the past to work around this problem, was adding **GoogleMaps** to all the modules (which will also cause the **GoogleMaps** binary to be loaded in each individual module), then write a `post_install` script inside the `Podfile` to parse through all generated `xcconfig` files via `Podfile` and remove all **GoogleMap** dependencies (`-framework GoogleMaps -framework GoogleBundle ...`). This way, you'll only have one loaded binary of **GoogleMaps** inside your application, but all your modules can see and work with **GoogleMaps**.

You don't need to manually parse through `xcconfig` files, `Cocoapods` does provide them in `post_install |installer|` and robust API for modifying them. You can check the [Cocoapod document](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/index) for more info. It will be something like:

```rb
# Static libraries
static_libraries = ['GoogleMaps', 'GoogleMapsBase', 'GoogleMapsCore']

target 'Application' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'Core' do
    project 'Core/Core'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

# Post Installer section
post_install do |installer|
    puts "Running post_install script"

    puts "Fix static_libraries"
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
        aggregate_target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
            config_file.frameworks.subtract(static_libraries)
            xcconfig_path = aggregate_target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
            config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I should also add, the same technique might be needed for other static libraries, like `Crashlytics`, `Fabric` and etc

Comment: Should I keep :modular_headers => true in GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces?

Comment: I didn’t in my implementation (TBH I don’t really know what will happen underneath when this option is on), I don’t have access to my system at the moment, I’ll update the answer when I access my previous implementation

Comment: that would be great! thanks! I'm not very proficient in Ruby if you could provide the post_install do |installer| script phase you used that would be awesome too

Comment: @rickrvo But as I was reading through Cocoapods documents, `:modular_headers` has been added for the same reason. Even if my implementation solves the problem, I suggest making the `:modular_headers` to work.

Comment: Thanks @farzadshbfn! Ill try that next week. Office is closed this week. I’ll let you know how it goes. But I did try modular_headers and it didn’t work before :/ lets hope your way works. Thanks again

Comment: I tried your solution but it got me some build time errors. :( I edited my question with the error. Please let me know if you experienced the same issue

Comment: @rickrvo did you add `core_pods` to the main application as well?

Comment: Yes I tried that too. Let me update my question to my current attempt

Comment: I managed to get passed that link error but still crashes with the original error

Comment: @rickrvo if It still crashes, Unfortunately I have no ideas.

Comment: :( Thanks anyway for the help! I'll keep trying dome combinations here to see if I can get it to work

Comment: Well the link error fix I tried from your solution might not be not really applying your solution. let me update my question again

Comment: @rickrvo well the one you printed, is the same as the one that I provided (#unless is commented out, am I right?)

Comment: yes! sorry I added the comment before changing the question... it's updated now

Comment: I managed to fix the link error with your solution too but the same crash appeared... I'm getting bald here lol

Comment: @rickrvo does it happen with GooglePlaces? or it happens with GoogleMaps as well?

Comment: You mean the crash? or the link error? the link error happened for GooglePlaces too now I cleaned them both. But the crash I'm not quite sure where the crash is happening if in GoogleMaps or GooglePlaces... like the error I'm getting now is :
objc[3766]: Class _NSZombie_GMSSTSDataRequest is implemented in both ?? (0x29e1bebd0) and ?? (0x29e161cd0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3766]: Class _NSZombie_GMSFeatureStyle is implemented in both ?? (0x29efbd950) and ?? (0x29efbcc10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: there is a bug report on cocoapods about this issue... It has been happening since version 1.1.0... we are now in 1.8.4 and still no solution
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5768

Comment: I might have to change my core dynamic framework to a static framework which I didn’t want to do...

Comment: I encapsulated the whole GoogleMaps library in a private pod that we were using dynamically inside our own projects. (with the trick that I provided), the trick was working with other static libraries though... I don't think doing what I did (encapsulating into a private pod) would fix you problem and it's a headache to make it working (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻